# Как получить файл из папки Downloads и добавить его в inputStream?

Tags: java, android

Я изучаю работу с файлами в android api (29). В моем примере берется csv файл из папки raw:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stats);
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы файл брался из папки Downloads, а не из raw:

```
File fileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File fileToGet = new File(fileDirectory,"stats.csv");
```

Как правильно произвести изменения?

Answer (score 0):

Для считывания данных из файла предназначен класс FileInputStream, который является наследником класса InputStream и поэтому реализует все его методы.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: в API 29 работают с файлами из внешних источниках через content URI

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести короткий пример? Я отмечу как решение.

Comment: Сначала нужно выяснить откуда у вас файлы взялись в папке Downloads, Например если вы пользуетесь DownloadManager - это будет одно решение и т.п.

Comment: Просто загружены вручную через браузер